# How do I replace space characters in a string with "%20"?

Tags: string, haskell, list-comprehension

I wanted to write a Haskell function that takes a string, and replaces any space characters with the special code %20. For example:

```
sanitize "http://cs.edu/my homepage/I love spaces.html"
-- "http://cs.edu/my%20homepage/I%20love%20spaces.html"
```

I am thinking to use the concat function, so I can concatenates a list of lists into a plain list.

Comment: You may want to look at concatMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
changer :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
changer [] res = res
changer (x:xs) res = changer xs (res ++ (if x == ' ' then "%20" else [x]))

sanitize :: [Char] -> [Char]
sanitize xs = changer xs ""

main = print $ sanitize "http://cs.edu/my homepage/I love spaces.html"
-- "http://cs.edu/my%20homepage/I%20love%20spaces.html"
```

The purpose of `sanitize` function is to just invoke `changer`, which does the actual work. Now, `changer` recursively calls itself, till the current string is exhausted.

```
changer xs (res ++ (if x == ' ' then "%20" else [x]))
```

It takes the first character `x` and checks if it is equal to `" "`, if so gives `%20`, otherwise the actual character itself as a string, which we then concatenate with the accumulated string.

**Note:** This is may not be the optimal solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Any idea how to use concat with it?

Comment: @WaleedAldeghaither `++` is the concat operator.

Comment: Yes I meant the concat function

Comment: @WaleedAldeghaither You can do it like this `changer xs (concat [res, (if x == ' ' then "%20" else [x])])`

Answer (score 3):

The higher-order function you are looking for is

```
concatMap :: (a -> [b]) -> [a] -> [b]
```

In your case, choosing `a ~ Char, b ~ Char` (and observing that `String` is just a type synonym for `[Char]`), we get

```
concatMap :: (Char -> String) -> String -> String
```

So once you write a function

```
escape :: Char -> String
escape ' ' = "%20"
escape c = [c]
```

you can lift that to work over strings by just writing

```
sanitize :: String -> String
sanitize = concatMap escape
```

Comment: Awesome! I like your way it makes me understand it pretty strong, and simple as well. Regards:)

Answer (score 2):

Using a comprehension also works, as follows,

```
changer :: [Char] -> [Char]
changer xs = [ c | v <- xs , c <- if (v == ' ') then "%20" else [v] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `intercalate` function from `Data.List` module. It does an [`intersperse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/Data-List.html#intersperse) with given separator and list, then concats the result.

```
sanitize = intercalate "%20" . words
```

or using pattern matching :

```
sanitize [] = []
sanitize (x:xs) = go x    xs
          where   go ' '  []     = "%20" 
                  go y    []     = [y] 
                  go ' '  (x:xs) = '%':'2':'0': go x xs  
                  go y    (x:xs) = y: go x xs
```

Comment: `intercalate "%20" . words` doesn't quite work, because `words` removes leading and trailing spaces, trims consecutive spaces to a single one, and uses `isSpace`, which is less picky than `(==' ')`.

Answer (score 0):

Another expression of Shanth's pattern-matching approach:

```
sanitize = foldr go []
  where
    go ' ' r = '%':'2':'0':r
    go c   r = c:r
```